# Is a DB column UNSIGNED?

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

With Perl DBI, how to check whether the given column of a DB table is unsigned?

The following code does not work as expected (with MySQL DB):

```
my $sth = $dbh->column_info(undef, $schema, $Table, undef);
while (my $Column = $sth && $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
  my $ColumnName = $Column->{COLUMN_NAME};
  my $data_type = $Column->{DATA_TYPE}; # SQL_DATA_TYPE does not work too
  my $type_info = $dbh->type_info($data_type);
  my $Unsigned = $type_info->{UNSIGNED_ATTRIBUTE};
  my $UnsignedInfo = defined($Unsigned) ? ", unsigned=>$Unsigned" : "";
  print $fh "  '$ColumnName' => {type=>'$Column->{TYPE_NAME}', nullable=>$Column->{NULLABLE}$UnsignedInfo},\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully you can pull this off with DBI if there is nothing native in that interface:

```
create table myTable
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    si int not null,    -- signed
    ui int unsigned not null    -- unsigned
);

insert myTable (si,ui) values (1,1),(-7,8);

SELECT data_type,column_type  
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
WHERE table_schema='so_gibberish' -- my database name
and table_name = 'myTable' AND COLUMN_NAME in ('si','ui');

+-----------+------------------+
| data_type | column_type      |
+-----------+------------------+
| int       | int(11)          |
| int       | int(10) unsigned |
+-----------+------------------+
```

Comment: DBI is Perl's engine-independent database interface. It can most definitely issue queries and retrieve their results :)